# React Localization

Tags: reactjs, forms, localization

I have an application that is using the react-i18next library for localization, which allows you to translate strings in your application by passing them into a function called t(), and then those strings are extracted to a .po file to allow us to translate them into their various cultures.

However, there are a couple parts of my application I'm having trouble figuring out how to localize.

1. In a couple spots in our application, we have a File Control (i.e. Form.Control type="file" or Form.File). Both of these controls render a button that either reads "Choose a File" or "Browse" (depending on which control tag you use). There doesn't seem to be a property to be able to set the label of the button for me to translate. Does anyone know how to go about this?
2. We also have a couple places in our application that have Select lists:

   {t("All Available Options")}

   {industryOptions.map((x) => (
   {x.Display}
   ))}

Aside from the default value of "All Available Options", the other elements of the list are pulled from the database. I'd like to think I could just wrap x.Display in the t() function, but I feel like that wouldn't work because the code doesn't have advanced knowledge of what those strings are to be able to add them to the .po file. How would I go about this?

Comment: If the data is minimum, you could map it with an object, otherwise make sure the database itself sends a JSON of strings that maps to different locales. In making the database responsible for locales, you needn't add locales over and over again, when something in the database changes. In our application, we load all the locales from server itself. Server maintains multiple JSON of different locales.